# how can I embed a carriage return in label

Tags: xpages

I've got several xpage labels laid out in a table.  The contents of the labels comes from a  Notes document.  To format the text nicely, I need to wrap some of the text.  The notes field in the document is of type Text.  I can't get the text to wrap.  I've tried a carriage return in the text in the document, I've tried

```
 <br> and [<br>]
```

but it still comes out as one line.

Any ideas?
thanks
clem

Comment: Have you tried &#013;

Comment: Just tried it but it didn't work -- just showed "&#013;" in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<br/>
```

but then you have to use a computed field instead of a label and set it's property of content-type to HTML to get the tags working.

Comment: Hey Oliver, thanks, that worked!  But I really, really wish there were a whine-emoticon b/c that's what I really need to do right now.  Man!  .. Now I've got a bunch of fields to redo! :-\  Thanks, tho, I appreciate the help.  Clem

Comment: This no longer seems to work.  Wonder if some xpages update has removed this "feature".